# How to count over rows and avoid duplicates?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

For a university project I have to calculate a kpi based on the data of one table. The table stores data about baskets of a supermarket and the shopped line items and their product category. I have to calculate a number of all product categories of products which were bought in a specific store. So in tables it looks like this:

```
StoreId   BasketID  CategoryId
1           1           1
1           1           2
1           1           3
1           2           1
1           2           3
1           2           4
2           3           1
2           3           2
2           3           3
2           4           1
```

As a result of the query I want a table which counts the distinct product categories over all basket associated to a store.
Something like this:

```
StoreId   Count(CategoryId)
1            4
2            3
```

If I do a not dynamic statement with hard values, it is working.

```
select basket_hash, store_id, count(DISTINCT retailer_category_id)
from promo.checkout_item
where store_id = 2
  and basket_hash = 123
GROUP BY basket_hash, store_id;
```

But when I try to write it in a dynamic way, the sql calculates the amount per basket and adds the single amounts together.

```
select store_id,  Count(DISTINCT retailer_category_id) 
from promo.checkout_item
group by store_id;
```

But like this it isn't comparing the categories over all baskets associated to a store and I'm getting duplicates because a category can be in basket 1 and in basket 2.

Can somebody pls help?!

Thx!

Comment: What would be the result for the "dynamic way" ?

Comment: Show us your dynamic query as well.

Comment: Well, that is the point, i dont really know how to build this query. I tried it like this : select store_id,  Count(DISTINCT retailer_category_id) from promo.checkout_item
group by store_id; But like this the query doesnt compare the basket associated to a store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your expected result, Do you want following statement?

```
SELECT StoreId,  COUNT(*)
FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT StoreId, CategoryId 
       FROM table_name
)
GROUP BY StoreId;
```

Please, replace "table_name" in statement by your table's name.

I'm not sure what is "dynamic way" meaning.

Comment: dynamic way just means not to write values in the statement. And i think the result of the count is still too high because i only have 500 categories in the db and your query counts up to 1000 categories per store...

Comment: This is exactly the same as the OP's `COUNT(DISTINCT CategoryId)`

Comment: If you have CategoryId=1 in BasketID = 1 and BasketID = 2 , it count only 1. It can't be duplicated by BasketID. Could you give me an example which record should count and which record shouldn't count? and which statement give you result is 500 categories?

Comment: @dnoeth Yes, it is but the OP's just edited after I answered.

Comment: Hey, u are complettly right with ur answer.  I just realized that the data was kind of incostitent. thx

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your requirements. This is what I suppose you mean:

```
with checkout_item (store_id, basket_hash, retailer_category_id) as (
    values 
    (1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,1,3),(1,2,1),(1,2,3),
    (1,2,4),(2,3,1),(2,3,2),(2,3,3),(2,4,1)
)
select distinct store_id, basket_hash, store_cats, basket_cats
from (
    select store_id, basket_hash,
        max(store_cats) over (partition by store_id) as store_cats,
        max(basket_cats) over (partition by basket_hash) as basket_cats
    from (
        select store_id, basket_hash,
            dense_rank() over (
                partition by store_id
                order by retailer_category_id
            ) as store_cats,
            dense_rank() over (
                partition by basket_hash
                order by retailer_category_id
            ) as basket_cats
        from checkout_item
    ) s
) s
order by 1, 2
;
 store_id | basket_hash | store_cats | basket_cats 
----------+-------------+------------+-------------
        1 |           1 |          4 |           3
        1 |           2 |          4 |           3
        2 |           3 |          3 |           3
        2 |           4 |          3 |           1
```